# Why is "Assembliess" missing in Reference Manager and only 3 target frameworks are shown?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I am using VS2019.
I have created a new VB.NET WinForms project.
It is set to use the .NET framework 5.0.

Now I wanted to add the following references:

System.Xaml, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase,  WindowsFormsIntegration

However, "Assemblies" is not visible in the Reference Manager.

Also, in this project I can only chose between 3 frameworks, but I have many more installed:

[image]

As one can see, when I open up a project that I have created earlier, I can see and select all of my frameworks:

[image]

What is going on here?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

There were 2 VB.NET WinForms app templates in the Create New Project window.

Microsoft devs did a great job naming them almost exactely the same.
Only when I selected

```
Windown Forms App (.NET Framework) 
A project for creating an application with a Windows Forms (WinForms) user interface
```

instead of

```
Windows Forms App 
A project template for creatinng a .NET Windows Forms (WinForms) app
```

... it would work.

[image]

Comment: Hi tmighty, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)